# Basic probability arguments applied to find a lower bound of the average length of a decipherable code

Tags: probability, combinatorics, information-theory, large-deviation-theory

I am reading **A Course on Large Deviations with an Introduction to Gibbs Measures
by Firas Rassoul-Agha and Timp Seppelainen.** On section 1.1 they apply the noiseless coding theorem to find a lower bound on the average length of a uniquely decipherable code. It's been a long time since I took probability so I might be a bit rusty, I am having trouble with a couple of statements at the end. Below you can see a picture with the equations in context .  **My questions are**

1. $\text{ "With probability s for symbol 1, the typical word of length $n$ has about $ns$ ones  }(1) $
2. Suppose we use code words of length $L$ to code these typical words. Then
   $$ 2^L \ge{ {n}\choose{\lfloor ns \rfloor}\tag{2}}$$
   Where do (1) and (2) come from?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With probability $s$ for symbol $1$, the typical word of length $n$ has about ns ones

The formulation is rather sloppy. I guess that "typical" here is not related with "typical sets". Informally:

Consider a random sequence of $n$ iid $\{0,1\}$ symbols, with $P(X=1)=s$. Then, with high probability, the number of ones is near $n s$.

This comes from [the law of large  numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)

More precisely, letting $X$ be the number of ones, we have that for any fixed $\epsilon >0$, as $n \to \infty$

$$P( | X/n  - s| > \epsilon) \to 0$$

A little stronger: $X$ has mean $n s$ and variance $n s (1-s)$. Hence, using [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality), $$P( |X - ns| > \alpha \sqrt{n}) \le \frac{s(1-s)}{\alpha^2}$$

so "nearly always" the number of ones falls in the range $ n s \pm \alpha \sqrt{n}$ for some $\alpha$.

For the second one:

Assuming $k=ns$ is integer, you have $\binom{n}{k}$ sequences with $k$ ones. With $L$ bits, you can produce $2^L$ different labels, hence you can code at most $2^L$ values.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly are you using the law of large numbers to get the statement? Like for instance, are you using convergence in probability or a.s? How do you translate the statement "with high probability the number of ones is near ns" in an equation that is supposed to result from the application of that law